# How to write new line in file in assembly

Tags: file, assembly

I use Windows 8.1 and an emulator for assembly 8086.

I wrote the assembly code below to write 2 messages in file, but it's not correct because it doesn't write newline between two messages.

> output : Masoud  Hosseini

```
data segment

    fname  DW  "c:\test.txt"
    len    DW  8   
    handel DW  ?
    endl   DB  13
    msg1   DB  "Masoud  "
    msg2   DB  "Hosseini"

ends

code segment
start:

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ah, 3ch  ;open file
    lea dx, fname
    int 21h

    mov handel, ax    ;save handel

    lea dx, msg1
    mov bx, handel
    mov cx, len
    mov ah, 40h
    int 21h

    lea dx, endl
    mov bx, handel
    mov cx, 1 
    mov ah, 40h
    int 21h

    lea dx, msg2
    mov bx, handel
    mov cx, len
    mov ah, 40h
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h    
ends

end start
```

Comment: ASCII 13 is the carriage return character. Try the sequence 13, 10 (carriage return, linefeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your filename is wrong. `INT 21h/3Ch` expects an ASCIIZ-string, i.e. ASCII bytes plus null (like C). You wrote a series of ASCII **words** without any delimiter.

2) Also `INT 21h/3Ch` expects the file attributes in CX. "Ralf Brown's interrupt list" is a good resource to look up the functions of INT 21h: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/ix/21/

3) The encoding of newline (endl) depends on the OS. DOS needs two bytes: 0Dh & 0Ah. Linux and modern Windows are satisfied with just 0Ah. Older Macs want to have 0Dh. These encoding bytes are to be write as characters.

4) At the end you have to close the file.

Example for TASM:

```
.MODEL small
ASSUME CS:code, DS:data

data segment

    fname  DB  "test.txt",0
    len    DW  8
    handel DW  ?
    endl   DB  0Dh,0Ah          ; CR & LF (DOS)
    msg1   DB  "Masoud  "
    msg2   DB  "Hosseini"

ends

code segment
start:

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ah, 3ch         ; CREATE OR TRUNCATE FILE
    lea dx, fname       ; DS:DX -> ASCIZ filename
    xor cx, cx          ; file attributes
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT
    jc err_exit

    mov handel, ax      ; save handel

    lea dx, msg1        ; ds:dx -> data to write
    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov cx, len         ; number of bytes to write
    mov ah, 40h         ; WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

    lea dx, endl        ; ds:dx -> data to write
    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov cx, 2           ; number of bytes to write
    mov ah, 40h         ; WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

    lea dx, msg2        ; ds:dx -> data to write
    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov cx, len         ; number of bytes to write
    mov ah, 40h         ; WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov ah, 3Eh         ; CLOSE FILE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h       ; Exit (0)
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

err_exit:
    mov ah, 4ch         ; Exit (AX)
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT
ends

end start


.MODEL small
ASSUME CS:code, DS:data

data segment

    fname  DB  "test.txt",0
    len    DW  8
    handel DW  ?
    endl   DB  0Dh,0Ah          ; CR & LF (DOS)
    msg1   DB  "Masoud  "
    msg2   DB  "Hosseini"

ends

code segment
start:

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ah, 3ch         ; CREATE OR TRUNCATE FILE
    lea dx, fname       ; DS:DX -> ASCIZ filename
    xor cx, cx          ; file attributes
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT
    jc err_exit

    mov handel, ax      ; save handel

    lea dx, msg1        ; ds:dx -> data to write
    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov cx, len         ; number of bytes to write
    mov ah, 40h         ; WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

    lea dx, endl        ; ds:dx -> data to write
    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov cx, 2           ; number of bytes to write
    mov ah, 40h         ; WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

    lea dx, msg2        ; ds:dx -> data to write
    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov cx, len         ; number of bytes to write
    mov ah, 40h         ; WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

    mov bx, handel      ; file handle
    mov ah, 3Eh         ; CLOSE FILE
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h       ; Exit (0)
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT

err_exit:
    mov ah, 4ch         ; Exit (AX)
    int 21h             ; DOS INTERRUPT
ends

end start
```

Comment: I use emulator, so it isn't these problems, when use 13,10, code compiles

Comment: Nowadays the most of us use an emulator. The last authentic MSDOS worked under the hood of WinME. Please tell us next time **which** emulator you use. If your emulator also emulates an old 8086 processor you will quickly reach its limits.

Comment: Despite the term ASCIZ, the MS-DOS character set is [CP437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), not ASCII.